# ¿Como hacer y ligar un archivo manifest para c en CodeBlocs que pida permisos de administrador?

Tags: c, codeblocks, manifest

Estoy intentando hacer un .manifest para mi programa en c con CodeBloks, con el objetivo de que pida permisos de administrador al iniciarse el programa.

El problema que tengo es que todas las páginas que encuentro me pone como hacerlo con visual studio que simplemente te crea el archivo .manifest con todo dentro y dicen que cambie una linea pero en codeblocks esa opción o no está o no la encuentro.

Además si al final alguien me pasa como sería ese archivo .manifest para que lo edite y ya (porque no lo encuentro en ninguna parte) No se como se haría para ligarlo. He visto que a lo mejor en el archivo de recursos.rc añadiendo una linea que fuese así:

```
1 24 "nombre.manifest"
```

Pero no se si estaría bien. Si alguien me pudiese ayudar se lo agradecería mucho porque estoy estancado.

Este es el código solo lo he hecho para ver si funcionaba.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    f=fopen("C:/Program Files (x86)/archivo.txt","wt");
    fclose(f);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba lo siguiente:

Creas un manifiesto (app.exe.manifest) similar al siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0">
    <assemblyIdentity version="2.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="X86"
        name="app.exe" type="win32" />
    <description>Mi App</description>
    <dependency />
    <!-- Identify the application security requirements. -->
    <trustInfo >
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel
                    level="requireAdministrator"
                    uiAccess="false"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

En el archivo de recursos `resource.rc` o como lo llames, añade la siguiente línea:

```
[X] RT_MANIFEST "app.exe.manifest"
```

Donde [X] será el ID que le toque al recurso.

Recompilas el proyecto y listo, ya debería estar el manifiesto embebido en el ejecutable

Comment: como puedo saber cual es la X?

Comment: @julianix la primera columna es un identificador único. Cada recurso debe tener un identificador diferente

Comment: @a vale gracias

Comment: no me funciona :'( al ejecutarlo no me salía el pop-up de dar privilegios de administrador. Es decir me decía que todo estaba bien pero no los pedía además luego me saltó una ventana diciendo que el programa no era compatible

Comment: @julianix he puesto más información en el manifiesto, a ver si así te funciona

Comment: sigue igual mira te pongo el codigo que tengo intentalo tu en tu ordenador tmbn para ver si funciona por si es a mi ordenador al que no le da la gana XD @eferion

Comment: A mi el programa me arranca perfectamente. No puedo verificar lo de la UAC porque mi cuenta en esta máquina es de administrador

Comment: a mi tambien me pone el hellow world pero no me crea el archivo. ¿Podría ser por el compilador? @eferion

Comment: Para este tipo de situaciones es preferible usar las herramientas de microsoft. La edición Comunity de VS te permite hacer esto con dos clicks y se integra perfectamente con todas las herramientas de Windows. Y es gratuíta

Comment: Como me has dicho me he descargado VS como no daba la opción de c normal he imaginado que era la visual c++ para escritorio lo que no se es esos dos clics que tu dices cuales son. @eferion

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124495/discussion-between-julianix-and-eferion).

Comment: @julianix VS tiene opciones para compilar C [video](https://youtu.be/iq_sBeiN-Qk)